# how to install externial moduels in brython

Tags: python, html, brython

i am trying to install the module requests but it is not working

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/brython@3.8.10/brython.min.js"> </script> 
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/brython@3.8.10/brython.js"> </script> 
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/brython@3.8.10/brython_stdlib.js"> </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="brython()">
        <script type="text/python">
            import requests
        </script>
        <input id="zone"><button id="mybutton">click !</button>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something simple like `import re` probably works in your setup.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

But `requests` is not part of python's standard library.
You will want to arrange for its dependencies separately.
https://pypi.org/project/requests/

---

https://pypi.org/project/brython-pack

> brython-pack packages your Python packages/files into a brython_modules.js.

Comment: how would you arrange for it's dependencies, thanks.

Comment: I offered a docu-pointer. I have never done it, but apparently in brython land it is common to hand that task to `brython-pack` and let _it_ worry about pulling in `requests`, `python-dateutil`, and whatever sundry additional deps your app might need. When I look at the three <script elements in your HTML, it seems pretty clear that they are bringing in python's standard libraries, but no additional deps, there's no pack in there. You will want to Read The Fine Manual to learn about the details.